# label as a parameter

Tags: c, reverse-engineering

```
void InitCallback(DWORD callback)
{
goto EndTramp;
Tramp:

 __asm
 {
  pushad
                call callback
                popad 
  ret 
 }
EndTramp:

 JmpPatch(0x6D8AC1, (DWORD)Tramp);
 return;
}
```

error C2065: 'Tramp' : undeclared identifier

How extract address from a label?

Comment: Why not just make Tramp a separate function ?

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a portable way to obtain the address of a label in C or its descendants.

I see you're on Windows with MSVC - it often helps to be explicit about platform (and, in this case, compiler) versions.  There might be a specific trick, but there probably isn't.

Maybe you're reverse-engineering some assembler code and need to incorporate more of the code in assembler.

Comment: I have working code but in 2 functions, one is a tramp and another is a patchfunc but it looks better when all is in the same function.

Comment: @Yulo: "looks better" ? With `goto` s ??? This must be some new definition of the word *better* with which I am unfamiliar.